# ffmpeg output scale not work with framerate

Tags: ffmpeg

**CLI:**
`ffmpeg -i 0.mov -vf scale=256x256 -filter:v fps=5 1.gif`

**OUTPUT:**
 Video frame rate 5 Size 512x512 "Original Size"
Webp will be better but that web server only accpet gif and i need small size
So Any Help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine all your filters into one filtergraph (or chain). Try:

```
ffmpeg -i 0.mov -vf scale=256x256,fps=5 1.gif
```

Meanwhile, both size and framerate can be adjusted w/out explicitly defining a filterchain. The following should do the same thing:

```
ffmpeg -i 0.mov -s 256x256 -r 5 1.gif
```

Comment: Thank you it's works
```ffmpeg -i 0.mov -vf "fps=20,scale=256x256" 1.gif```
appreciate.